# Is it possible to install ubuntu frontend on lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, gui

I been playing around with lubuntu on VM and I really enjoy how fast it boot up.. so I think this might be a more suitable OS for my 8 years old laptop (lenovo G480)...

but the problem is, I really dont like the frontend of lubuntu, since it's base on ubuntu, I wonder if it's possible to convert the frontend of lubuntu back to ubuntu?

thanks.

edit: for clarification, by frontend, I mean the OS desktop enviroment.

Comment: The main point of lubuntu is it is light weight. So I think that the answer is no.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking sorry, what do you mean by *frontend*?   Are you asking about the DM (display manager), in which case we can't currently help you anyway as you've not provided any details as to what Lubuntu you're using (a *legacy* release soon to be EOL or a *modern* release as they are different). If it's that, then yes it can be changed, but I'm not sure it'll make any difference to boot speed though

Comment: You can add the Ubuntu desktop (*we still don't know your release, so don't know which DESKTOP you're talking about or will get as it's release specific*), with the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` which will result in you having two desktops (again release specific, Unity7 or GNOME for Ubuntu & LXDE or LXQt for Lubuntu, depending on release). You can also remove one, but the effects will vary on your release (*unknown as you didn't provide as requested*) and apps you use (Lubuntu switched from GTK2 to Qt5 five releases ago so that's a large jump and thus consider app choice & RAM..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install any additional desktop on an Ubuntu release. To install the regular desktop, issue the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

This will pull in all packages deemed essential for the default Ubuntu desktop.

Once installation is successful, you can switch to that new desktop environment on the log-in screen. Click the cog wheel and select the Ubuntu desktop session before entering your password.

The regular Ubuntu desktop is, of course, not as lightweight as the Lubuntu desktop, so take that into account.

If you wish to undo the change, then take your precautions when installing `ubuntu-desktop`. The command will list all packages that are going to be installed. Copy these into a file, in case you later want to remove the Ubuntu desktop again. It is not possible to automatically do so by removing the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage, followed by an autoremove, because core packages installed with it are marked as "manually" installed, even if you pulled them in through this metapackage.